# How to make Marker on GoogleMaps in iOS change it's position without animation

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am working on a GPS tracking app using GoogleMaps for using the Maps.

Right now I am working on simple feature lets say there is a slider and as we move the slider the marker on the Map moves corresponding to the marker.

I am getting what I want to do but there is just a small issue.

The position of marker can be changed by this code -

```
marker.position = positionArray[valueFromSlider]
```

The only problem I am facing with this method is that Marker moves with the animation it looks very good in normal use case scenario but the problem that occurs is that if someone slides the slider too frequently then marker don't follow the proper path i.e.., `Polyline`.

Because following the proper path is a requirement so I tried removing the marker from the map and again putting it on the map but it looks very jerky and I did it by the following code whenever the method is called (slider is moved).

```
marker = nil
marker.position = newPosition
marker.map = mapView
mapView.animate(to: GMSCameraPosition(target: newPosition, zoom: 13, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0))
```

and the other way I tried it was this way I am pasting the actual code here in this way result was better then the above one but not as desired I mean it was just slightly better than the above one

```
func jumpToNext(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
mapView.clear()
remap(location: location)
mapView.animate(to: GMSCameraPosition(target: newPosition, zoom: 13, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0))
}
```

Here is declaration of `remap` function

```
    func setMarkerOnMap(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
    marker = nil
    marker = GMSMarker(position: location)
    marker.map = bottomMap
    path.add(location)
    path = GMSMutablePath()
    for (index, locationB) in subTrips.enumerated(){
        path = GMSMutablePath()
        var polylineColor = UIColor()
        switch locationB.speed {
        case 0..<20:
            polylineColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        case 20..<40:
            polylineColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0, green: 162/255, blue: 232/255, alpha: 1)
        case 40..<60:
            polylineColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 34/255, green: 117/255, blue: 76/255, alpha: 1)
        case 60..<80:
            polylineColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        case 80..<100:
            polylineColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 255/255, green: 165/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
            print("crossed 80 at index ", index)
        default:
            polylineColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 237/255, green: 28/255, blue: 36/255, alpha: 1)
            print("crossed 100 at index ", index)
        }

        if index == 0{
            path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude))
            path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locationB.latitude, longitude: locationB.longitude))
        } else{
            path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: subTrips[index - 1].latitude, longitude: subTrips[index - 1].longitude))
            path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locationB.latitude, longitude: locationB.longitude))
        }

        var polyline = GMSPolyline()
        polyline.path = self.path
        polyline.map = self.bottomMap
        polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
        polyline.strokeColor = polylineColor

        polyline.geodesic = true
        polyline.strokeWidth = 2.0
        polyline.map = bottomMap

    }

}
```

Now what I want to achieve is that when I change the location of the marker then it just disappears and then appears on a new location without animating on the map.

Comment: What I want is that when I change the position of the marker then instead of being in animation way it just disappears from the current position and jumps to a new position so even if someone slides very fast then it covers all the points in between.

Answer (score 2):

what if we remove the marker, 
using

```
marker.map = nil
```

and add a new marker at new location, which will solve your problem..

```
func jumpToNext(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
        marker.map = nil
        remap(location: location)
        mapView.animate(to: GMSCameraPosition(target: newPosition, zoom: 13, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0))
}
func remap (location: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
        marker = GMSMarker(position: location)
        marker.map = bottomMap
       //other stuff you want to do you can do that here
}
```

This should solve your animation problem..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but i was facing the same issue, and i solved it by just not using a marker, and placing a fixed UIImageView over the GMSMapView with a drop marker image instead.

Whenever i need to retrieve tha map position, i just get it from the camera instead of the marker:

```
    let latitude = mapView.camera.target.latitude
    let longitude = mapView.camera.target.longitude
```

Answer (score -1):

`GMSMarker` has [`opacity`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#change_the_marker_opacity) property. You can set it to 0, then set new `position` and again set `opacity` back to 1(with some delay).

Comment: Man, Thanks for the answer. But this will not work because the problem I am facing with `marker.location = newLocation` is that it doesn't animate properly. So I just want to remove the animation.